# AVAudioPlayer initWithData returning nil

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, nsdata

I have used the following code to initialise an AVAudioPlayer object with NSData, which in turn has the data of an mp3 in my main bundle.

```
NSError *error;
NSString *filePathForBgAudio = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"beebuzz10" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSData *bgAudioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePathForBgAudio];
bgAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:bgAudioData error:&error];
bgAudioPlayer.delegate = self;
```

I have declared `bgAudioPlayer` in the `.h` file. But when I checked by setting breakpoint, I found that after this line `bgAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:bgAudioData error:&error];` the `bgAudioPlayer` is still shown to be `nil`. But the `filePathForBgAudio` and `bgAudioData` are initialised correctly and has data. just the `bgAudioPlayer` is `nil`. What is the problem in the above code? How to rectify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                         pathForResource:@"bubble"
                                         ofType:@"mp3"]];

    NSError *error;
    _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                    initWithContentsOfURL:url
                    error:&error];
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@",
              [error localizedDescription]);
    } else
    {
        _audioPlayer.delegate = self;
        [_audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

    }
}


- (IBAction)playsound:(id)sender
{

    [_audioPlayer play];

  }
```

Comment: #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

Comment: You were using the `initWithData:error:` method, which load a NSData object of your MP3 file, whereas he uses `initWithContentsOfURL:error:` which directly points to this file in your bundle

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSError *error;
    NSURL *filePathForBgAudio1 =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"beebuzz10" ofType:@"mp3"]];
    //NSString *filePathForBgAudio = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"beebuzz10" ofType:@"mp3"];
   // NSData *bgAudioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePathForBgAudio1];
   bgAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:filePathForBgAudio1 error:&error];
```